# linux crontab fails with google api drive

Tags: python, linux, cron, google-drive-api

I have a python script that downloads files from google drive through the API, it's perfect to run it manually but when I want to automate it with crontab it doesn't download anything and it doesn't send errors to the log I defined. I am using absolute paths -> `05 20 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/etl1/download.py`, also I have the headers configured in my script

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
# - * - coding: utf-8 - * -
```

I have also given permissions to everything, but I can't. instead the Upload script that writes to BigQuery goes perfectly with crontab.

I would appreciate if someone could support me

Answer (score 0):

**first of all** - you have whitespaces in `/usr /bin /python3` so you can try `/usr/bin/python3`

**and second**, try:

```
05 20 * * * $(which python3) /home/user/etl1/download.py >> ~/cron.log 2>&1
```

https://gavinwiener.medium.com/how-to-schedule-a-python-script-cron-job-dea6cbf69f4e